# How to change date column type to `yyy-mm-dd` format while inserting data using SqlBulkCopy in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, date

In my application, inserting that data using `SqlBulkCopy` into SQL Server. In  I need to insert this type like (yy-mm-dd).

This is my code:

```
SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
objbulk.DestinationTableName = "tblname";

// mapping the columns 
bjbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Month", "Date");
con.Open();

objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
con.Close();
```

Comment: If the column in excel is set to DateTime and the SQL database is also set to DateTime you should not have to do anything special.

Comment: Since `SqlBulkCopy` is highly optimized for **speed**, it doesn't allow to do any conversion / lookups or any other operations during its running. Either you need the speed and you just insert your data **as is** (and handle any additional steps later on), or you have to use something other than `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: Dates have no formats, if that's what you are asking. There is no `yy-mm-dd` type, that's just a (buggy) string format that can be used to format *any* of the date-related types. You can save a `DateTime` value to any of the date-related field types

Comment: Are you asking how to store a `DateTime` value to a `date` field? You don't need to change anything. `DateTime` values are mapped to `date` fields directly.

Comment: Are you trying to save a *string* with a `yy-mm-dd` format to a date-related field? Then you have a bug. You are trying to store a string into a date field. Change the type of your `Month` column to `DateTime` and parse your string data into DateTime values when you load them into the data table